# Save Firebase - Firestore Database to JSON or CSV?

Tags: json, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, export-to-csv

I created a react-app for a study, where I save many different datas on a Firestore database.
Now that the study is over, I want to save those datas as a json or better as a .csv-file.

Is there an easy way to get this done? I searched for a solution, but somehow couldnt find anything...

Comment: [node-firestore-import-export](https://github.com/jloosli/node-firestore-import-export#readme) is a helpful npm package for this

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-cloud-firestore%5D+export+csv